# What is an effective way to isolate/segregate AWS users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-iam

I am trying to give temporary access to AWS console for a few users (for a limited time), and they should not be able to view any resources created by the other users. These are the possible methods I could find:

1. Creating an *IAM user* for each user and assigning IAM policies: This is a straightforward process, but would it be possible to define the policy in such a way that every user is completely isolated from each other? The user should be able to create any resource, but view and manage only his resource. After use, the *IAM user* can be deleted to revoke access for the user to the AWS console.
2. Creating an *AWS account* under the root account *Organization*: This would guarantee isolation, but deleting a managed AWS account is not straightforward and hence this method does not seem viable.

Can anyone help me with a possible solution?

Edit:  I am trying to dynamically create accounts/users on demand. (Thanks for pointing it out @JamesKn)

Answer (score 2):

I would get them each to sign up for AWS and then run consolidated billing http://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/consolidated-billing.html

That way they would be completely isolated but you would get one bill.

Comment: This would work, but I want to dynamically create accounts/users on demand.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/APIReference/API_CreateAccount.html might help you ? I am not sure. You probably want to add that bit of detail into the question. As it kind of key ;)

Comment: Again, that would work. But managed accounts under an organization cannot be easily deleted (you'd need to contact AWS support). Since I'm trying to give temporary access for a limited time, this approach is also not ideal.